# HorizonatalScrollView on TabWidged "steals" space

Tags: android, layout, tabs, horizontal-scrolling

I have an TabActivity with custom TabWidgets at the bottom. I want to be able to add more than 5 Tabs. Unlike the MenuBar, which adds a "more" button dynamically, Tabs are just resized and look horribly. So my first attempt was to wrap my TabWidgets into a HorizontalScrollView. The problem is, that I have a ListView as TabContent and its last item seems to be hidden behind my TabWidgets. 
This is the Layout for my TabView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/main_linlay_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <TabHost 
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/main_tablinear"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent">
      <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@android:id/tabs"/>
      <HorizontalScrollView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <TabWidget
          android:id="@android:id/tabs"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_gravity="center"/>
      </HorizontalScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
  </TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

am I doing something wrong in my Layout? Are there better ways to apply more than 4 Tabs? While I can see 4 Tabs good with my Nexus-S, I'm thinking they are already ugly on a Wildfire. Any idea appreciated

Comment: Does it only start scrolling if you add more than 4 tabs?  Mine has 5 tabs and it still squeezes everything in...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem myself! I think it can be helpful for other users to see the soltution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/main_linlay_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <TabHost 
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/main_tablinear"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent">
      <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dip"/>
        <!-- note: margin bottom 50 dip above: 
           its exactly the size of my custom TabWidget  -->
      <HorizontalScrollView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <TabWidget
          android:id="@android:id/tabs"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_gravity="center"/>
      </HorizontalScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
  </TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It worked for me:

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<TabHost android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
        <HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                <TabWidget android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs" android:isScrollContainer="true"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:scrollbars="horizontal"></TabWidget>
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
        <FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@android:id/tabcontent">
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/tab1"></LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/tab2"></LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/tab3"></LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/tab4"></LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/tab5"></LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost></LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what are the LinearLayouts with id/tabX for? I add Tabs Programmaticly in Java with TabSpecs

Comment: Markis Hi, I just tried it without these Layouts, with the same result: one List-item is missing, and as soon as I remove HorizontalScrollView it appears.